# Boolean Tool is not cutting properly

Tags: modifiers, knife-tool

I am currently trying to make a 5 gang box faceplate for 5 drok meters to measure power. I was able to use the boolean tool to cut out the screw holes and one of the meter inserts. However, when I use the boolean tool again to try and cut the other 1.5 slots, it fails to cut my main object and the previous cut will fill back in. I have also tried making a cube to size vs my "cookie cutter shape" and it fails as well. What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to cut this?[image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file because we can only see a minor part of your settings. Or read the hundreds of questions here about boolean problem - i am sure they would help you.

Comment: I have checked several which is why I tried adding the cube instead. Im sure you can tell im still very new at this. The file has been uploaded. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Boolean modifiers will only work with manifold geometry and right face orientation.

You can check your face orientation here:

[image]

So click "viewport overlays" and check "face orientation".

Blue means: ok, red means: wrong face orientation.

You can repair this by selecting the meshes which are red, TAB -> edit mode -> A (select all) -> SHIFT-N -> recalculates normals. Then the mesh should turn blue.

After you repaired all your meshed, and it still won't work, pls upload your repaired blend file. Thanks.